# Xsd Schema Namespace

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, namespaces

Please consider below PspShoppingCartServiceRequest.Xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.com"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.com"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:common="http://www.example.com/common"    
    <xs:import namespace= "http://www.example.com/common" schemaLocation="common.xsd" />
    <xs:element name="PspShoppingCartServiceRequest" type="tns:PspShoppingCartServiceRequest" />
    <xs:complexType name="PspShoppingCartServiceRequest">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="PspRequestHeader" type="common:PspRequestHeader" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="PspShoppingCartServiceRequestBody" type="tns:PspShoppingCartServiceRequestBody" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="PspShoppingCartServiceRequestBody">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="PspShoppingCart" type="tns:PspShoppingCart" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="OrderId" type="common:OrderIdType" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Common.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema
  targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/common"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  xmlns:common="http://www.example.com/common"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:complexType name="PspRequestHeader">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="MerchantId" type="common:MerchantIdType" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="RequestDatetime" type="common:RequestDateTimeType" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="RequestReferenceNumber" type="common:RequestReferenceNumberType" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Language" type="common:PspLanguageType" />
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I know there are missing parts on xsds. I didn't write all of the elements because we don't have to look at that parts

I expect that my PspRequestHeader must be in namespace "http://www.example.com/common", but when I try to validate coming xml, if it does not contain "PspRequestHeader" element, XDocument.Validate class throws

> The element 'PspShoppingCartServiceRequest' in namespace
>   'http://www.example.com' has invalid child element
>   'PspShoppingCartServiceRequestBody' in namespace
>   'http://www.example.com'. List of possible elements expected:
>   'PspRequestHeader' in namespace 'http://www.example.com'.

Should not it be example "http://www.example.com/common"?

Comment: element PspShoppingCartServiceRequestBody is not defined in the xsd.

Comment: You will need to show us all three files, the main schema you have shown, but of course we need to see `common.xsd` and the input XML as well if you want us to explain the message.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh,  I have added, Could you please investigate now. Thanks

Comment: @MartinHonnen,  I have added, Could you please investigate now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as the targetNamespace is `http://www.example.com`.

If the input xml is missing `PspRequestHeader`, then this is what the message would show.  Per the declaration, it is required as it has `minOccurs=1` and `maxOccurs=1`.

This is because the element is a local element declaration that specifies the type of the element as `common:PspRequestHeader`.  You should declare a global element in `Common.xsd`:

```
<xs:element name="PspRequestHeader" type="common:PspRequestHeaderType" />
<xs:complexType name="PspRequestHeaderType">
  <xs:all>
    <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="MerchantId" type="common:MerchantIdType" />
    <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="RequestDatetime" type="common:RequestDateTimeType" />
    <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="RequestReferenceNumber" type="common:RequestReferenceNumberType" />
    <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Language" type="common:PspLanguageType" />
  </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

And refer to it in `PspShoppingCartServiceRequest` using the `ref` attribute:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" ref="common:PspRequestHeader" />
```

Comment: Thanks for answer Charles. I am trying to validate my coming xml against xsd. So, I know PspRequestHeader is missing. I want to catch this case.  targetNamespace is http://www.example.com, I know but I define PspRequestHeader  as type="common:PspRequestHeader". So, It should be belongs to http://www.example.com/common namespace. Am I wrong? I am wrong, could you please show how can I move it to http://www.example.com/common namespace

Comment: @osman See update - not tested, but it should be a good start!

Comment: Thanks for your help Charles, It is working now. But please correct your first line; <xs:element name="PspRequestHeader" type="PspRequestHeaderType" /> --> <xs:element name="PspRequestHeader" type="common:PspRequestHeaderType" />

Comment: it must like type="common:PspRequestHeaderType"

Answer (score 0):

change the schema location like this and try:

```
<xs:import namespace= "http://www.example.com/common" schemaLocation="../common.xsd" />
```